# How to visualize data from firebase and display on gauge chart

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gauge, google-gauges

I tried to get data from firebase to display on gauge chart but it's doesn't show anything and shown error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown type of value in 0,1

Here's my js code.

```
var db = firebase.database();
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['gauge']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(tempLevel);

function tempLevel() {
var temp = db.ref('monitor').child('deviceId').child('temp').once('value')
.then((dataSnapshot) => {
this.tempArray = dataSnapshot.val();
});

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Temp', temp]
]);

var options = {
    width: 250, height: 250,
    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90,
    minorTicks: 5
};

var chart = new 
google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('temp_level'));

chart.draw(data, options);

setInterval(function () {
    data.setValue(0,1);
    chart.draw(data, options);
}, 13000);
}
```

What does it mean about this code?

```
data.setValue(0,1);
```